# Reference variables/functions in a module from inside that module in Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm programming an elevator controller. It uses an 'API' module with functions like `OpenDoor()` and values like `Floor`. How can I use these values from within the module?

I've tried using `self` with no luck.

```lua
local API = {

Lift=script.Parent,

--and now the problem

LiftCar=(self?).Lift.Car,

}

return API
```

When I tried using `self` I got an error because `self` didn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no modules in Lua as a language feature, only tables and lexical scopes.

If you are using a table to represent your module (which you do), you'll have to address it like a table: `LiftCar = API.Lift.Car`, which in your case will be impossible, since local `API` is not yet defined at the moment the assignment would be parsed.

[This chapter](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.html) of the Lua book sums up various ways of making modules.

Two simplest ways would be either to define the table beforehand:

```
local API = {}
API.Lift = script.Parent
...
```

Or to define everything as local and populate the table afterwards:

```
local function myfunction() do_something() end
local API = {my = myfuncion}
```

With the first alternative being the [preferred one](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide).

Comment: Thanks, these are known as modules in ROBLOX lua though.

Comment: In Lua a *module* is something you `require`. The table is really more of an implementation detail than anything else, but the terms are *almost* interchangeable when the table is the return value of a call to `require`. To be 100% specific you'd say it's the *module table*, where "table" describes what it is and "module" describes its purpose. Anyway, for the purpose of this question they can just be treated as being the same thing.

Comment: I prefer the second method as it is not affected by name changes of the return table. Actually simpler, just return the table directly without naming it.

Answer (score 1):

In Roblox lua, just like DarkWiiPlayer mentioned, you can include ModuleScripts in your other scripts using the `require` function.

So let's say you've got your Elevator object defined like this in a ModuleScript :

```
local Elevator = {}
Elevator.__index = Elevator

function Elevator.new()
    local e = {
        currentFloor = 1
    }
    setmetatable(e, Elevator)
    return e
end

function Elevator:OpenDoor()
    print("Opening Door to : ", self.currentFloor)
end

return Elevator
```

Another script that is placed next to it could include its code like this :

```
local ElevatorModule = require(script.Parent.Elevator)

local anElevator = ElevatorModule.new()
anElevator:OpenDoor()
```

The reason why your code is complaining that `self` doesn't exist is because of how you've defined your functions.
There is a difference between : `function Elevator.OpenDoor()` and `function Elevator:OpenDoor()` (notice the colon as opposed to a period).

When you use a colon to define a function, a hidden variable `self` is inserted as the first argument.

A good example of this is the [string library](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) :

```
-- repeat a string 5 times
local hw = "Hello World"
print( string.rep(hw, 5) )

-- works the same way as...
print( hw:rep(5) )

-- which (stupidly) also works the same way as...
print( hw.rep(hw, 5) )
```